# No GUI Access to VPN Connections | OpenVPN | 16.04 Loki Beta Daily PPA

Tags: openvpn, release-loki

I recently did a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 using the mini.iso and installing a headless CLI environment.

I then added the elementary os daily PPA and ran:

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop

Reboot... and I now have a fully functioning elementary OS Loki Beta [yay]
Full functioning... but network manager applet doesn't list VPN options after installing Open VPN.

for VPN I ran the sh script found here:
https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/ubuntu-openvpn

which worked fine in 14.04 despite it being intended for 12.04.
The script did error at the very end with:

Restarting network manager..
Error: Object 'nm' is unknown, try 'nmcli help'.
Error: Object 'nm' is unknown, try 'nmcli help'.
Install successful!

I looked at the script... and those two lines just reference restarting the network manager [which I did manually... and it didn't fix the issue].

There's literally nothing after that in the script other than "echo install complete"

So, why, after a reboot... can I still not access my list of VPN connections?

Any workarounds would be much appreciated.
THX

Answer (score 1):

You are installing beta software so expect these problems. You should report them on LaunchPad instead of asking them here and they might fix it

Comment: Yes.... I have already let them know via launchpad.