# Can I connect to my VPN through GUI in Loki beta

Tags: settings, release-loki, networking, openvpn, vpn

Is it still possible to connect through the network applet somehow? I installed network-manager-openvpn-gnome, but I can't find anything in the network settings. There is only the "Proxy" option under virtual. 
Has support for managing VPN connections through GUI been dropped?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: is that working now?

Answer (score 2):

Currently elementaryOS's Switchboard Network Plug doesn't support VPN connections.

This question have been previously asked before ([No GUI Access to VPN Connections | OpenVPN | 16.04 Loki Beta Daily PPA](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/5495/no-gui-access-to-vpn-connections-openvpn-16-04-loki-beta-daily-ppa))

Since then the Devs have been notified and currently there are 2 bug reports about this:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-networking/+bug/1416249
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-networking/+bug/1427248

Keep in mind that Loki is still in beta and under development.

I can only advise you to check the above bug reports and mark them as "**Yes, it affects me**" under "**This bug affects # persons. Does this bug affect you?**"

Comment: Thank you, There is also this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-networking/+bug/1440563

Today for a while I had two network indicators and one allowed me to import my ovpn configurations and even activate them through it, but after a reboot it's gone. Very weird.

Comment: Developers are working on simple VPN configurator now: https://code.launchpad.net/~donadigo/switchboard-plug-networking/vpn